# Difference between PanResponder and GestureResponder

Tags: react-native

Can someone more experienced explain how the `Pan Responder` differs from the `Gesture Responder` and when it is better to use them.

---

**Document:**

**Pan Responder:**

https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder

**Gesture Responder:**

https://reactnative.dev/docs/gesture-responder-system

Answer (score 1):

The Gesture Responder System is the basic system of how gestures are managed in React Native.

PanResponder is built on top of it and gives you a little more comfort when working with it. It also holds an InteractionManager to prevent interruption of active gestures.

While the Gesture Reponder System only provides you the native touch events, Pan Responder also provides you a gestureState object, which contains the state of the whole gesture (from starting the touch until releasing the finger). This can make your life a lot easier, since you don't have to calculate everything on your own.

If you don't need this gestureState or the properties provided by the gestureState objects are not sufficient for your use case, you could work directly with the Gesture Responder System. Otherwise I would recommend using PanResponder.